# Dynamically filling 4 canvases based on length input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html5-canvas

I have created 4 different canvases in design file of my aspx file.

The first 3 having length 300 and last having length 100.

There are various 10 different length inputs coming dynamically for these. Once the length crosses 300, I am unable to switch to 2nd canvas.

Here goes my code:-

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas4" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
    

<script type="text/javascript">
        
        var prod1head = '<%=head[0]%>';
        var prod2head = '<%=head[1]%>';
        var prod3head = '<%=head[2]%>';
        var prod4head = '<%=head[3]%>';
        var prod5head = '<%=head[4]%>';
        var prod6head = '<%=head[5]%>';
        var prod7head = '<%=head[6]%>';
        var prod8head = '<%=head[7]%>';
        var prod9head = '<%=head[8]%>';
        var prod10head = '<%=head[9]%>';
            
        var prod1color = '<%=prd_color[0]%>';
        var prod2color = '<%=prd_color[1]%>';
        var prod3color = '<%=prd_color[2]%>';
        var prod4color = '<%=prd_color[3]%>';
        var prod5color = '<%=prd_color[4]%>';
        var prod6color = '<%=prd_color[5]%>';
        var prod7color = '<%=prd_color[6]%>';
        var prod8color = '<%=prd_color[7]%>';
        var prod9color = '<%=prd_color[8]%>';
        var prod10color = '<%=prd_color[9]%>';
        
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        
        ctx.fillStyle = prod1color;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, prod1head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod2color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod1head, 0, prod2head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod3color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod2head, 0, prod3head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod4color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod3head, 0, prod4head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod5color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod4head, 0, prod5head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod6color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod5head, 0, prod6head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod7color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod6head, 0, prod7head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod8color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod7head, 0, prod8head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod9color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod8head, 0, prod9head, 50);
        ctx.fillStyle = prod10color;
        ctx.fillRect(prod9head, 0, prod10head, 50);

</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but I don't even see any attempts of switching canvases or even tracking length...

Comment: Exactly, I am unable to decide when the head tag length crosses 300 in the code above and switch to second canvas dynamically

Comment: just use `Math.ceil(head / 300)` I guess. It will give you number from 1 to *nn* which you can use to select proper canvas

Comment: Why not use only one canvas and set the width and height to what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You could just draw the same shape to all canvas with an offset by the position of the canvas...

In your code you have not really attempted much, you have only one `ctx` variable, but you have 4 canvases, the first it to loop over all your canvas and add the needed information to an array, that we can later loop and do the drawing.

Instead of the many `fillRect` you have on your code, we can create a common function that we call with the right params it will draw in all the canvases taking the offset into account, the offset we can calculate using getBoundingClientRect, you can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

See a working prototype below:

```js
var canvases = []
for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  const c = document.getElementById("canvas" + i)
  canvases.push({
    ctx: c.getContext("2d"),
    rect: c.getBoundingClientRect()
  })
}

function fillRect(color, x, y, w, h) {
  canvases.forEach((c) => {
    c.ctx.beginPath()
    c.ctx.fillStyle = color;
    c.ctx.fillRect(x - c.rect.left, y - c.rect.top, w, h)
  })
}

function strokeArc(color, x, y, r, lw) {
  canvases.forEach((c) => {
    c.ctx.beginPath()
    c.ctx.lineWidth = lw;
    c.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    c.ctx.arc(x - c.rect.left, y - c.rect.top, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    c.ctx.stroke();
  })
}

fillRect("red", 10, 10, 100, 28)
fillRect("blue", 20, 20, 500, 20)
fillRect("black", 2, 2, 6, 200)
fillRect("black", 300, 2, 6, 200)
strokeArc("cyan", 220, 160, 150, 5)
strokeArc("black", 300, 50, 30, 20)
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" width="300" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas4" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
```

That should output something like:

[image]